# How to kill all nvidia processes for a single GPU

Tags: bash

1. First, nvidia-smi does not even show the processes, so I cannot use that in any way.
2. `for i in $(lsof /dev/nvidia0 | grep python  | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u); do kill -9 $i; done`

The above command **does** kill all nvidia processes (even invisible ones), but it does so across all GPUs. How can I kill all processes belonging to a single GPU only?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but as an aside, `... | grep foo | awk '{bar}'` can always be replaced with `awk '/foo/ { bar }'`.

Comment: As for the question, though -- right now it requires knowledge about things that are more operating-system details than bash details. If you know how to _list_ processes using a specific GPU, that would scope this down towards being a question _about bash_, vs about Linux and nvidia's drivers (where knowledge of bash is only of secondary utility if that).